# Run C# application from cmd

Tags: c#, exe

I have made a application in c# and it works OK now I want that exe should be able to run from the command prompt.
Application take input a .txt file and produce .txt file

**Ex:-C:\user\abc>xyz.exe INPUT.txt**

**C:\user\abc>OUTPUT.txt is saved.**

Comment: can you elaborate what is not working for you and what you have tried ?

Comment: Check this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/main

Comment: If you are using Visual studio the easiest option is to create a new Console Application project.  This will create a main function that you can modify.

Comment: Actually I dont know any procedure.......

Comment: Don't know any procedure ... please explain this is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Command Line Argument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb20e19t.aspx) for your console application, so that you can pass argument from command line to the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Developer command prompt for VS if you have installed Visual Studio on your PC.You can find developer command as given below.

Start => Developer Command Prompt for VS

Then you can use Command Line Arguments to pass your text file. Actually the location of the text file as a string. That string will be caught by the main method. That is why main method has a array of strings. You can fetch all the arguments you pass into the program from the string array parameter inside the main method.

`static void main(string[] args)`